# View page count in Twig template

Tags: views, 8, paging

I can't seem to figure out how to get all this information in one line in a views template.

```
<div class="pagination--totals">
  Page @current_page of @page_count <small>(@total Results Results)</small>
</div
```

I can get the total result with `{{ view.pager.total_items }}`. I can get the current page with `{{ view.pager.current_page }}`. I can't get the page count, though.

I can get the page count in a preprocess function for the pager, but that doesn't really get me the value I need, where I need it.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function acc2019_preprocess_pager(array &$variables) {
  // @see globals.api.php
  global $pager_total;

  $element = $variables['pager']['#element'];

  // Get the max page number for the current pager.
  $variables['pager_max'] = $pager_total[$element];
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get that value in my views-view.html.twig template in any way.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you can get the view in your preprocess function you can probably get the count with any of the methods found in this post https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2797565, or if you want count directly in a view perhaps this https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/count-views/ can help.

Comment: You probably also need to bust the cache somehow. Otherwise this variable only gets updated on cache flushes.